# ERROR when trying to pick a first time profile name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I try purchase minecraft I get to the pay part, I put in my details and it says pick a profile name, it then says 'Due to an error we are currently unable to check if the profile name you want is available.

Not Found: The server has not found anything matching the request URI

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: @imulsion yes of course

Comment: Have you tried banging on Mojang's servers? (Quite literally, because this sounds like a problem on their side)

Comment: @aytimothy yeah I sent them a email...just wanted to know if anyone has had the problem....I have strange feeling they wont reply to.

Comment: Still doesn't work? [Check here!](http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/) It should work when Session and Login is Online.

Answer (score 1):

It can be because of how you spelled your name: Your profile name can't contain SPACEs. Instead, you can replace spaces by "_".

Answer (score 0):

If it's not working, contact Mojang for customer support. Check your WiFi/Ethernet, too.